# PHP script redirection

Tags: php, scripting, redirect

I need help on redirect of php scripts. The problem is: I have a page for example www.domain.com/redirect.php?id=34 that redirects to another page, domain2.com/product.php?id=2. I need to create a script that allow me to know the URL of the redirection (domain2.com/product.php?id=2) just by accessing the redirector (www.domain.com/redirect.php?id=34). Anyone have a an idea? tanks! ;)

Comment: url of redirection is obviously known in the redirector script;), make the question clearer please

Answer (score 3):

One solution is opening socket to www.domain.com, sending request, waiting reply and reading/parsing HTTP "Location: ...." header.

Or if you are using PHP 5.0 or above you can take advantage of [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php).

```
$url       = 'http://www.google.com/';
$headers   = get_headers($url, 1);
$redirect  = isset($headers['Location']) ? $headers['Location'] : '';
```